# Encrypted drive on windows 10 locked after recovery

Tags: windows-10, encryption, bitlocker

I have followed this article to enable encryption on one of my windows drives: (method1)
http://windowsreport.com/encrypt-files-folders-windows-10/amp/

1. Enable encryption on the drive using the advanced button in the General tab of drive properties
2. Export EFS certificate (.pfx file) using a password

Now after some time I needed to recover my pc using a full system image I created before but the drive is locked and I can't unlock it!
I only have a .pfx file and a password (no recovery keys) but when I try to open the drive it asks me for a numerical recovery key!
Is there a way to unlock the drive?

Comment: Did you re-import the PFX file (which is a combined certificate and private key) into the system you're using to try and recover the encrypted files? After importing the key (and associated cert, which is done in the same operation) and providing the password to decrypt the key, Windows should be able to recover the EFS-encrypted files.

Comment: "Is there a way to unlock the drive?" - If you don't have the private key then you won't be able to do this.  My comment is based on the fact you indicated you imported the public and private keys, but it isn't working, which indicates to me there is a chance the keys you have imported are not correct

Comment: @CBHacking yeah I did import the certificate and it's in my personal certificates but the drive is still asking me for a recovery key!

Comment: @Ramhound Believe me I did export the keys the same way that article says but now it doesn't work! The data in that partition is really important to me but it's locked for some stupid reason! :(

Comment: Thank you for your comments guys... should I do anything after importing the certificate or should it unlock the drive instantly?

Comment: Try adding the certificate (and key) to the machine store, rather than the user store?